# wget not working failed: No route to host

Tags: wget

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. Every time I use `wget` I get

```
failed: No route to host
```

for every website. What could be the issue here?

```
root@zubuntubase:~# ping -i 3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
ping: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key: Name or service not known
```

```
root@zubuntubase:~# ping -i 3 google.com
PING google.com(ord36s04-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:800::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ord36s04-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:800::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=99.9 ms
64 bytes from ord36s04-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:800::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=64.0 ms
64 bytes from ord36s04-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:800::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=76.9 ms
64 bytes from ord36s04-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:800::200e): icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=67.7 ms
64 bytes from ord36s04-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:800::200e): icmp_seq=5 ttl=52 time=68.1 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 12013ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 64.006/75.326/99.850/12.971 ms
```

```
root@zubuntubase:~# ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.78 metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.78 
192.168.1.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.78 metric 100


root@zubuntubase:~# ping 192.168.1.78
PING 192.168.1.78 (192.168.1.78) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.78: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.368 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.78: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.78: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.081 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.78: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.081 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.78 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3030ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.079/0.152/0.368/0.124 ms 

I found out my problem virtualbox is only connecting to google services.
```

Comment: Can you open the websites in a browser like Firefox ?

Comment: What does `ip route` show? How are you connected to the Internet?

Comment: Try `ping` and `traceroute` with those sites.

Comment: Yes I can use firefox.

Comment: root@zubuntubase:/home/administrator# traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (172.217.4.110), 64 hops max
  1   192.168.1.1  2.733ms  4.485ms  12.664ms 
  2   *  *  * 
  3   96.34.88.180  18.564ms  22.130ms  16.981ms 
  4   96.34.88.186  14.668ms  14.537ms  28.446ms 
  5   96.34.88.3  15.651ms  15.451ms  21.519ms 
  6   96.34.89.13  17.402ms  23.957ms  17.049ms 
  7   96.34.0.164  41.497ms  39.773ms  41.259ms 
  8   96.34.3.35  35.637ms  40.030ms  44.226ms 
  9   72.14.242.180  37.726ms  39.398ms  36.191ms 
 10   *  *  *

Comment: root@zubuntubase:/home/administrator# ping google.com

--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3008ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 62.022/67.012/72.935/4.019 ms

Comment: It seems like you have some latancy or unreliable network, but it maybe not the cause of this problem. Are you using Ubuntu desktop? Does using a web-browser work for you? If yes, then maybe it is your `wget` command that is wrong: please **edit your question** add the full command syntax you are using. Also, while editing, **please add** your comments regarding the `ping` and `ip route` commands you've tried (simply copy-paste them), and use the **{}** (code sample) formatting option.

Comment: Done editing my post.

Comment: 7 hours ago @Pizza said "maybe it is your wget command that is wrong: please edit your question add the full command syntax you are using". Since your use of `ping` is incorrect, then this seems likely. Please do it.

Comment: What do you need me to ping?

Comment: @zustudios Please [edit] your question and add the *complete* `wget` command you're using, for example, `wget https://example.com`, with complete error message.

Comment: I found out my problem virtualbox is only connecting to google services.

Answer (score 2):

`ping` accepts hostname only. From [URL - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL):

> A typical URL could have the form `http://www.example.com/index.html`, which indicates a protocol (`http`), a [hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) (`www.example.com`), and a file name (`index.html`).

Also, from [Syntax - Hostname - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Syntax):

> Hostnames are composed of a sequence of [labels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_label) concatenated with dots. For example, "en.wikipedia.org" is a hostname. Each label must be from 1 to 63 characters long. The entire hostname, including the delimiting dots, has a maximum of 253 ASCII characters.

Clearly, `https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key` is URL while `google.com` is hostname. That's why, in your case `ping` worked perfectly with latter one.

---

#### Further Reading:

- [ping(8) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ping)
- [Difference between pinging with and without http://](https://superuser.com/q/930498/1049284)
- [Can you get a reply from a HTTPS site using the Ping command?](https://superuser.com/q/326403/1049284)
- [Is pinging a website essentially the same as visiting the website through a browser?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/129436)

Comment: This answer currently doesn't have details about `wget` since currently `wget`'s details are incomplete in the question itself. This answer only explains why `ping` is working in one of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was unplug and plugin my router.